# Python: Memory error when running fit_transform with StandardScaler

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have a huge dataset with over 300+ columns, and since 90% of those columns are categorical in nature, i decided to one-hot encode them which resulted in a dataset of shape (466557, 1778). I am trying to scale this data using:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing as p
scaler = p.StandardScaler()
df_ss = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

However, i am running into memory error.

```
MemoryError            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-d766bc7d2870> in <module>()
```

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't standard scale dummy variables ! 
Standard scaling is made to transform a continuous variable to a variable with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.
Since you used One Hot encoding the categorical variables are now only made of 1 and 0 (1 for True if that binary variable is present 0 for False else):

I might also add that you might have other memory error later in development if your dataset is too large.
Check each categorical feature and check if their not ordinal (you can order them) if they are don't use One hot encoder but replace values by a number (with respect with the order). If you're working with large cardinality categorical you can also use the hashing trick. But in a more general way I would advise you to look for better ways to encode your categorical variables!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to scale each row separately?

Comment: How would you do that? A code snippet might be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I am working without some pieces of your code.. I assume the df is a pandas data frame?

The standard scaler simply removes the mean and divides by the standard deviation, see
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html.

Something like:
for column in df.keys():
    mean,std = df[column].mean(),df[column].std()
    df[column] = (df[column]-mean)/std

Should scale the columns, assuming they are float/integers.

If this does not solve the memory problem, you could even update the columns in chunks.

Comment: I hope that helps! It's difficult helping if I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: thank you Helmer. I will try this out and see. Although, i excluded one-hot encoded columns and reran scaling only on the numerical columns which did the trick for me.